# Gaussian elimination in matrix, how to proceed?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here it's the matrix I need to reduce (I report my attempt)

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
6 & (3+2h) & (5-2h) & -2k - 2 \\
-3 & (h-4) & (2-h) & 7 - k \\
6 & 2h & (5-3h) & (-3k-8)
\end{array}\right)$$

Firstly I exchange the first row with the second:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-3 & (h-4) & (2-h) & 7 - k\\
6 & (3+2h) & (5-2h) & -2k - 2 \\
6 & 2h & (5-3h) & (-3k-8)
\end{array}\right)$$

Now I subtract to the second and third row, 2 times the first row

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-3 & (h-4) & (2-h) & 7 - k\\
0 & (4h-5) & (9-4h) & 12-4k \\
0 & (4h-8) & (9-5h) & (6-5k)
\end{array}\right)$$

Last step I try is $(4h-5)$Row3 $-(4h-8)$Row2 and I obtain this:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-3 & (h-4) & (2-h) & 7 - k \\
0 & (4h-5) & (9-4h) & 12-4k \\
0 & 0 & -(4h^2+7h-27) & -(4hk+24h+7k-66)
\end{array}\right)$$

Which is not correct: in fact that's what my exercise reports as "solution":

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
3 & h & 1 & 1 \\
0 & (h-2) & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & (h-1) & (k+2)
\end{array}\right)$$

What did I miss?

Comment: Be careful when you sum the second row with 2 times the first

Comment: Are you positive that you typed everything correctly? Because the first and the last matrix that you wrote don't have same solutions.

Comment: @Ennar, When fixed I didn't do the work "with my hands" but I used WolframAlpha to fastly put the correct result, so it should be fine...

Checked again and got the same result!

Comment: I meant literally the first and the last. The last as in "reported solution".

Comment: @Ennar: then probably who wrote the book has done some column exchange. Is it possible?

Comment: Baffo rasta, matrix rank would still be preserved. The first (non-augmented, 3 by 3) matrix is of full rank for $h = 1$, while that's not the case for the last one (again, non-augmented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now as you subtract to the second and third row, $2$ times the first row:

The $(2,2)$-entry should be

$$4h-5$$

Comment: damn you're right!

Comment: Still, even fixing this, I still don't get the expected result...

Comment: sorry with late response, i was sleeping. Ennar is right.